# If $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a+\epsilon, b]$, does it imply $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

The problem goes like:
Suppose that $f\in B[a,b]$. If $V^b_{a+\epsilon}f\leq M$ for all $\epsilon >0$, does it follow that f is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$?

I think the answer is yes. Since $V^b_{a+\epsilon}f$ is uniformly bounded and f is also bounded, also since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have f is of bounded variation of $[a,b]$. Is this correct?

Comment: The key point is of course the uniform bound, i.e., the fact that $M$ does not depend on $\epsilon$ in the precise formulation in the body of this post  (but this is not the case in the question in the title of this post)

Comment: Just curious as to why the assumption that $f$ is bounded?  If $V^b_{a+\epsilon}f\leq M$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $f$ must be bounded anyway on $(a,b]$ by $M + |f(b)|$ and so $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ by $M+|f(a)|+|f(b)|$.

Comment: "...as it is it makes no sense" is sometimes more commonly expressed on this website by the phrase "I don't understand the argument."  Fix $a<x<b$ then $$|f(b)-f(x)| \leq V^b_{a+\epsilon}f\leq M$$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$.  Hence $|f(x)|\leq M + |f(b)|$.  Thus $M + |f(b)|$ is an upper bound for $f$ on $(a,b]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, if $a$ is a point of a given partition, then it is sufficient to take $\epsilon$ sufficiently small to make sure that the next point is already in $[a+\epsilon,b]$. Boundedness of $f$ takes care of the first interval.

Comment: One thing to add perhaps.  What is your best estimate for $V_a^b f$?

Comment: It would be the same bound, right?

Comment: Almost the same.  (Function need not be continuous here.)

Comment: $V_a^b f \leq M+\lim_{c\to a^+} \sup\{|f(a)-f(x)| : x\in (a,c]\}\leq M+\sup_{x\in (a,b]}|f(a)-f(x)|.$  E.g. if $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (a,b]$ and  $f(a)=1$, with $M=0$; and $V_a^bf=1.$

Comment: How about $M+\limsup_{x\to a}|f(x)-f(a)|$?

Comment: Yes (if you change $x\to a$ to $x\to a+$).  But that is the same as the version given by @user254665.

Comment: The notation $c\to a^*$ just means that $c$ converges to $ a$ thru values greater than $ a.$

Comment: ;-) I leave it here, but you were the one asking, not me. All is exactly I as say above.

Comment: Both answers here are equivalent to $V_a ^b f \leq |f(a+)-f(a)| +  M$.   So perhaps we can, indeed, leave it here.

Answer (score 4):

Since the other answer is more a wave of the hand than an answer one would submit to 
your instructor I thought a proper, economical, write-up might be welcome.   (Not that there is anything wrong with "hand-waving"
we all do it:  the intention is "Here is the idea -- You write it up yourself now.")

Also the other
 poster was less than pleased by the discussion and asked (one presumes) for details.

> **Problem**.  Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ have the property that the variation $V_c^b f \leq M$ for all $a<c<b$.  Show that $f$ has bounded
>   variation on $[a,b]$ and that $$V_a^b f \leq M + |f(a+)-f(a)|.$$ In
>   particular, if $f$ is continuous on the right at $a$, then  $V_a^b f
>   \leq M$.

First observe that, for any $a<x<b$ 
$$ |f(b) -f(x)| \leq V_x^b f  \leq M.$$
Hence $|f|$ is bounded on $(a,b]$ by $M+|f(b)|$.

Now take any  subdivision
$a=a_0<a_1  <a_2< \dots < a_n=b$ and 
any $a<t<a_1$.  Observe that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n |f(a_{i+1})-f(a_i)| \leq 
 |f(t)-f(a)| +  |f(a_1)-f(t)| + \dots +|f(a_n)-f(a_{n-1})|
$$
$$
  \leq  |f(t)-f(a)|  + M  .$$
This is true for all such $t$ and $f$ is bounded, so
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n |f(a_{i+1})-f(a_i)| \leq \liminf_{t\to a+}
|f(t)-f(a)|  + M< \infty.$$

Since this is true for all such subdivisions of $[a,b]$ 
we have 
$$ V_a^b f  \leq \liminf_{t\to a+}
|f(t)-f(a)|  + M$$
and so $f$ has bounded variation on $[a,b]$.

All functions of bounded variation are regulated (i.e. they have finite right and left hand limits at each point) and
so 
$$\liminf_{t\to a+}
|f(t)-f(a)| = \lim_{t\to a+}
|f(t)-f(a)| = |f(a+)-f(a)|$$
completing the proof.

Comment: Just a question, what if the partition is inifinite? like in the case of $x^{-2}sin(1/x)$

Comment: The definition for variation of a function on an interval uses finite partitions.   So for all purposes (proofs/examples/applications) that is all you need.  If you really *want* to use an infinite sequence, say $0 < ...< a_{n+1}< a_n < ... < 1$ with $a_n\to 0$ to estimate the variation for $x^{-2}\sin x^{-1}$ on $[0,1]$  you  would fix an integer $m$ and use the finite partition $\{0, a_m,a_{m-1}, ..., a_1, 1\}$.   So, while it appears you are using an infinite partition you would write it up using this finite partition.  That help?

Comment: Downvoted perhaps out of spite?  This answer is intended more as a elaboration since the problem as posed had a redundancy (assuming $f$ is bounded) and did not ask, as it should, for a best estimate on $V_a^b f$,  If you don't like the elaboration, please do downvote.